# Reporting Progress from COM/STA Thread to WPF UI thread

Tags: c#, wpf, com, sta, acrobat-sdk

I working on an application that prints PDFs using COM and the Acrobat SDK.  The app is written in C#, WPF and I am trying to figure out how to run the printing correctly on a separate thread.  I have seen that a BackgroundWorker uses the thread pool and therefore cannot be set to be STA.  I do know how to create a STA thread, but am unsure how I would report progress from a STA thread:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(PrintMethod);
thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA); //Set the thread to STA
thread.Start(); 
thread.Join(); //Wait for the thread to end
```

How do I report progress to my WPF ViewModel in a STA thread created like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually not, you need to report progress not **from** but **to** an (already existing) STA thread, in which the UI runs.

You can achieve this either through `BackgroundWorker` functions ([`ReportProgress`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.progresschanged.aspx) is delivered on the thread which started the `BackgroundWorker` -- this should be your UI thread), or using the UI thread's `Dispatcher` (usually with `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`).

---

Edit:
For your case, the solution with `BackgroundWorker` won't work, as its thread is not STA. So you need to work with just usual `DispatcherlInvoke`:

```
// in UI thread:
Thread thread = new Thread(PrintMethod);
thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA); //Set the thread to STA
thread.Start();

void PrintMethod() // runs in print thread
{
    // do something
    ReportProgress(0.5);
    // do something more
    ReportProgress(1.0);
}

void ReportProgress(double p) // runs in print thread
{
    var d = this.Dispatcher;
    d.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
            {
                SetProgressValue(p);
            }));
}

void SetProgressValue(double p) // runs in UI thread
{
    label.Content = string.Format("{0}% ready", p * 100.0);
}
```

In case your current object does not have a `Dispatcher`, you can take it from your UI objects or view model (if you use one).

Comment: But the COM component needs to run in a STA thread as well, and I don't want it to run in the UI thread as it takes quite awhile.

Comment: @jle: Yes, the COM can run in its own STA thread. The UI thread is anyway an STA as well. If you cannot use `BackgroundWorker` (because its worker thread is not STA), you can report progress with just `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`.

Comment: So there is this: http://dotnetventures.wordpress.com/2011/07/30/maintaining-a-wpf-applications-ui-responsive-while-calling-com-objects/, which shows how to do it, but I don't understand why I would do that when I could just create a thread with dispatcher?

Comment: That's a win--makes sense now.

Comment: @jle: indeed, an extra thread like in the article you mention is not really needed.